# how to solve a groovy/grails tool suite reference?

Tags: java, linux, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've been working on my desktop computer which has openjdk 7.

When I copy a Grails project onto my laptop, which has Oracle's JDK v7, I'm having a problem with the classpath.

I've checked the classpath and everything seems fine.

Here's the text that GGTS shows:

```
The archive: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar which is
referenced by the classpath, does not exist
```

I set the JAVA_HOME inside /etc/profile.

I installed gvm in order to make easier Groovy and Grails setup.

I hope you could help me

:)

Comment: No offense, but the answer is pretty obvious - you have something in the project files that is hard-coded to the wrong directory. grep for it.

Comment: `grails integrate-with --eclipse` to adjust your project on the new machine.

Comment: @SérgioMichels not a good idea to run that command.  It is only useful if you are not using Grails-IDE.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Can you explain why? I always ran this command and solve references issues, also in STS...

Comment: Good question. :-)  In older versions of STS (pre-3.0) this may have helped things.  But now if it still helps it's by accident.  For 3.0, we did some work to make sure that the IDE is better at reading grails projects that do not have any eclipse metadata already available in it.

Answer (score 1):

I then went to the **RUN menu option** at the top and selected **run configuration**

It was on :  **Grails \ {Myproject} (run-app)**

On the right for this run-app there is JRE options

under JRE ensure you have the same JRE defined as project in this case 1.6

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your JRE reference in your project is bad.  Is your desktop windows and your laptop a mac or linux (or vice versa)?

Try these things:

1. Does the /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar path exist on the broken system?
2. Can you create other kinds of projects on the broken system?
3. Can you create a new Grails project from scratch inside of the broken GGTS?
4. What happens if you run Grails -> Refresh dependencies on the project?

Comment: both are linux, the main problem is the jdk difference, one is using oracle's jdk and in the other one i'm using openjdk

Comment: @JuanReséndiz Updated the answer with some questions.